# Discard year and month on rails date select not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, datepicker

I'm trying to get a form date select to show day only...

This works and shows month only:

`<%= f.date_select :some_date, {discard_day: true, discard_year: true} %>`

However this does **not** work and show date only:

`<%= f.date_select :some_date, {discard_year: true, discard_month: true} %>`

What's the correct configuration just to get a list of days?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should use manual select for days

Answer (score 0):

You can't get what you want from the `date_select` helper. If you take a look at the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select), you'll find this little tidbit:

> :discard_month - Set to true if you don't want to show a month select.
>   This includes the month as a hidden field instead of showing a select
>   field. *Also note that this implicitly sets :discard_day to true*.

(Emphasis added)

You're going to have to use a normal select to get days only.